# New to jQuery and need help appending things during events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently, I'm try to create a button that, when clicked, updates a 'feed' div. I want it to create three elements: a `tweet(<div>)`, a `message(<p>)`, and a `username(<p>)`. Then, I want it to append both the message and the username to the tweet div, then append the tweet div to the feed div. (knock off twitter for a learning project)

This is the event handler i have right now:

```js
/* edit note: what is $button???? */
$button.on('click', function() {
  $feed.empty();
  for (var i = tweet.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var user = tweet[i];
    console.log(user);
    var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
    var $message = $('<p class="message"></p>');
    var $username = $('<p class="username"></p');
    console.log(user.message);
    $message.text(user.message);
    $message.appendTo($tweet);
    $tweet.text('@' + $message);
    $tweet.appendTo($feed);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Need more HMML here!</div>
```

When I click the button, I get `'@ [object Object]'`.

I would like to know how to get the text from the data structure to render correctly on the 'feed'.

Data structure is formatted this way:

```
{
user: 'douglascalhoun', 
message: ' installed my future ', 
createdAt: Wed Feb 15 2023 15:01:02 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
profilePhotoURL: './assets/img/user-3.png'
}
```

Comment: When concatinating the message to `"@"` you need to concatinate the *string the message is in* and not the *jQuery object containing a paragraph containing that string*. You used the wrong variable. Voting to close as "caused by typo" as this kind of trivial error isn't going to be of value to future visitors.

Comment: Although that said, setting the text of `$tweet` after appending the paragraph to it is going to destory the paragraph making several of the previous lines completely pointless.

Comment: I made a snippet of your code but the JavaScript is incomplete and it would greatly help if you added relevant HTML that reproduces your issue.

Comment: what is `$feed`?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss $feed is a div. I've read jQuery docs for upwards of 5 hours and I am having a really hard time understanding or remembering some stuff. I updated the code to use the attributes to select them, its rendering now but i would like to render it inline. '@ [username] [user message]. The course i'm doing requires no hardcoding of HTML. Everything must be rendered using jQuery. This is the first day i've ever used it. Please be easy.

Answer (score -1):

I think I see where you are going with this.
Here I setup a fake tweet thread and the used it in the event handler.  I added some CSS just to give visual clarity.

```js
// setup a JavaScript object with date fixed to an actual date
// well this is not great: Wed Feb 15 2023 15: 01: 02 GMT - 0600(Central Standard Time),

// setup fake tweets object: I just set up for the example since the question was about the jQuery part.
const baseDate = new Date("2023-02-15T15:01:02.000+06:00");
const bsec = baseDate.getSeconds();
const sample = [{
  user: 'douglascalhoun',
  message: ' installed my future ',
  createdAt: new Date(baseDate.setSeconds(bsec + 20)),
  profilePhotoURL: './assets/img/user-3.png'
}, {
  user: 'willieb',
  message: 'Ate my bananna',
  createdAt: new Date(baseDate.setSeconds(bsec + 45)),
  profilePhotoURL: './assets/img/user-3.png'
}, {
  user: 'charliewoods',
  message: 'Need more input',
  createdAt: new Date(baseDate.setSeconds(bsec + 16)),
  profilePhotoURL: './assets/img/user-3.png'
}].sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt);
//console.log(sample);
const $button = $('.add-more');
const $feed = $('.feed-me');

$button.on('click', function() {
  // assumes we want a new clean feed each time
  $feed.empty();
  const tweet = sample;
  //console.log(tweet,tweet.length);
  const startat = tweet.length;
  //console.log(startat,tweet[0]);
  for (let i = startat; !!i; i--) {
    const userTweet = tweet[i - 1];
    //console.log(i-1,userTweet);
    // create three objects
    const $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
    const $message = $('<p class="message"></p>');
    const $username = $('<p class="username"></p');
    // add text to the message and username objects
    $message.text(userTweet.message);
    $username.text(userTweet.user);
    // append the message to the tweet object
    $message.appendTo($tweet);
    //put this text at the start of the username object
    $username.prepend('@');
    // add the user to the start of the tweet and append it to the fee;
    $tweet.prepend($username);
    $tweet.appendTo($feed);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
 .tweet{
 display: flex;
 
}

.tweet {
  border: solid 1px lime;
}

.username {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

.message {
  border: cyan 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="add-more">Add More</button>
  <div class="feed-me">empty</div>
</div>
```

Second example to hit DOM one time for each new "batch" of tweets and removed comments.  I updated the datetime to simulate new tweets and added a time formatted to the end to illustrate removal of those over a "capacity" value - so in this example we only show up to 7 at a time.

```js
function getTweets() {
  // to simulate whatever is used to go get tweets
  // setup fake tweets object: from NOW 
  const baseDate = new Date();
  const bsec = baseDate.getSeconds();
  const sample = [{
    user: 'douglascalhoun',
    message: 'installed my future',
    createdAt: new Date(baseDate.setSeconds(bsec + 20)),
    profilePhotoURL: './assets/img/user-3.png'
  }, {
    user: 'willieb',
    message: 'Ate my bananna',
    createdAt: new Date(baseDate.setSeconds(bsec + 45)),
    profilePhotoURL: './assets/img/user-3.png'
  }, {
    user: 'charliewoods',
    message: 'Need more input',
    createdAt: new Date(baseDate.setSeconds(bsec + 16)),
    profilePhotoURL: './assets/img/user-3.png'
  }].sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt);
  // console.log('returning tweets', sample.length);
  return sample;
}
const feedParameters = {
  getem: getTweets,
  feed: $('.feed-me')
};
// use the feedParameters for the function and feed objects
$('.add-more').on('click', feedParameters, handleAddMore);

function handleAddMore(event) {
  //use the parameter objects
  const tweets = event.data.getem();
  const $feed = event.data.feed;
  // use this data to put a "cap" on number shown
  const capacity = $feed.data('capacity');
  const $newTweets = $('<div class="newtweets" />');
  tweets.forEach(userTweet => {
    // just create from template literals and append it to the new tweets
    //Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
    $('<div class="tweet" />')
      .append(`<span class="message">${userTweet.message}</span>`)
      .prepend(`<span class="username">@${userTweet.user}</span>`)
      .append(`<span class='tweet-time'>${userTweet.createdAt.toISOString().substring(11, 19)}</span>`)
      .appendTo($newTweets);
  });
  $newTweets.find('.tweet').appendTo($feed);
  // remove any extra first N over capacity
  let removeCount = $feed.find('.tweet').length - capacity;
  if (removeCount > 0) {
    let extra = $feed.find('.tweet:nth-child(-n+' + removeCount + ')').remove();;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.tweet {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px lime;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.username {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

.message {
  border: cyan 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.tweet-time {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.test {
  background-color: #ddddff44;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="add-more">Add More</button>
  <div class="feed-me" data-capacity="7"><span class="tweet">empty</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GennadiyMostovskiy Also note I would not consider this a "finished production ready" code block.  Key is note how the elements are created (as jQuery objects); updated and then appended as a "chunk" to the DOM.  Multiple ways this might be done with the same results. Read up on `append`, `appendTo`, `prepend` , `after`, `before`, `prependTo`,  in the manipulation group http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Also note: these would be better in this loop to append to a new div created locally and then append them all at once to the DOM not one by one in this `for` loop thus ONLY hitting the DOM one time

Comment: Understood. Ill refactor some stuff to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: I took a couple minutes over lunch to add an example that only hits the DOM once each click and shows a limited number at a time.